# Read custom action from the Open Graph beta

Tags: facebook-graph-api

Is it possible to read the actions & objects created with the new Open Graph?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I might be wrong (did not test) but according to [these docs](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/beta/authentication/read/) you'd need the following extended permissions

```
user_actions.{vertical_name}
friends_actions.{vertical_name}
```

or

```
user_actions:{app_namespace}
friends_actions:{app_namespace}
```

Comment: According to Facebook this is currently only possible for the author of the app. 3rd parties still need to wait until the open graph is officially released.